# Twitter bootstrap and max-width for mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I would like to set the fixed with for mobile devices on 320px - I would like to want to look my website always the same as on [the screen for 320px](http://mattkersley.com/responsive/).

I have tried to set up the fixed width on 320px, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    body {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work me. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the meta tag in your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=320, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

Comment: some of that isnt necessary, but the first couple of arguments are (user-scalable, initial-scale, maximum-scale, minimum-scale)

Comment: @sevenseacat Once target-densitydpi helped me on android

Comment: Could it be the solution to this issue, if yes how? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851785/can-i-explicit-define-minimum-pixel-width-on-which-bootstrap-should-switch-to-re