# can I explicit define minimum pixel width on which bootstrap should switch to responsive mobile version?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap responsive and either I am doing something wrong, or bootstrap is not so responsive as I would love it to be.

Below you see 4 possible states, and I would avoid the two in middle. Either everything is inline like in first case, or force bootstrap to be "mobile" like in case 4.

**QUESTION** Can I set minimum width in pixels on which Bootstrap will always be in this mobile look like shown in case 4?

I am using twitter bootstrap version 3
here is code responsible for navbar https://gist.github.com/andilab/c1eba569dd0b9b9ad280

case 1: OK
[image]

case 2: BAD
[image]
case 3: BAD
[image]
case 4: OK
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Lots of ways to do it, but I think the easiest is to download a custom Bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize. Specifically see this note:

> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport
>   is narrower than @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its
>   horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least
>   @grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Less
>   source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value
>   is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

And make that change here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system. In your case, you would change `@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-sm-min` to `@screen-md-min`.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap.css file contains `@Media` rules that define the `min-width` at which it swtiches to the mobile layout.

You shouldn't edit the bootstrap.css file directly but you could override the `min-width` in a custom CSS file.

Comment: could you provide an example of how to override it?

Answer (score 1):

The full and working solution should be focused on the resolution on which the navbar menu should be collapsed to: [image].

working demo http://www.bootply.com/98488 by [@Skelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/skelly)

The answer can be found here: 
[Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar-collapse - set width to collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703550/twitter-bootstrap-3-navbar-collapse-set-width-to-collapse)

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_responsive_utilities.htm

You can use responsive utilities classes.

For example in your header container you can add hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-sm and on most mobile phones and tablets your menu will be like in your case 4.

Hope this is what you were looking for.